# ¿Cómo restar valores de dos consultas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ando buscando una solución para realizar una resta de dos select que están sumando campos, tengo las siguientes query pero no logro como realizar la resta de ambas query, (una es un select a una tabla normal y la otra es un select de una vista).

```
SELECT 
((SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1,
       sum(mueble2)  AS mueble2,
       sum(mueble3)  AS mueble3,
       sum(mueble4)  AS mueble4
FROM  stock_muebles)-

(SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1,
       sum(mueble2)  AS mueble2,
       sum(mueble3)  AS mueble3,
       sum(mueble4)  AS mueble4
FROM vv_muebles)) AS TOTAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las puedes hacer por separado, de esta forma:

```
SELECT 
( SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1 FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1 FROM  vv_muebles )
```

Si las quisieras hacer todas juntas, tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
SELECT 
( SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1 FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1 FROM  vv_muebles ),
( SELECT sum(mueble2)  AS mueble2 FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble2)  AS mueble2 FROM  vv_muebles ),
( SELECT sum(mueble3)  AS mueble3 FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble3)  AS mueble3 FROM  vv_muebles ),
( SELECT sum(mueble4)  AS mueble4 FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble4)  AS mueble4 FROM  vv_muebles )
```

Puedes entonces simplificar el query así:

```
SELECT 
( SELECT sum(mueble1) FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble1) FROM  vv_muebles ) AS mueble1,
( SELECT sum(mueble2) FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble2) FROM  vv_muebles ) AS mueble2,
( SELECT sum(mueble3) FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble3) FROM  vv_muebles ) AS mueble3,
( SELECT sum(mueble4) FROM  stock_muebles )
-
( SELECT sum(mueble4) FROM  vv_muebles ) AS mueble4
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Gepser tu solución me ha funcionado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sencilla es:

```
SELECT sum(mueble1)  AS mueble1,
       sum(mueble2)  AS mueble2,
       sum(mueble3)  AS mueble3,
       sum(mueble4)  AS mueble4
       FROM (SELECT mueble1, mueble2, mueble3, mueble4
                    FROM  stock_muebles 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT  mueble1 * -1, mueble2 * -1, mueble3 * -1, mueble4 * -1
                    FROM  vv_muebles
            )
```

Básicamente con un `union all` juntamos todas las filas salvo que las de las segunda tabla la sumaremos en negativo.